# Collapse Duplicate Answers

Tags: feature-request

On questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429746/why-doesnt-gcc-like-this) there are many answers that are only slight deviations of each other. It would be great if there was a way to close, delete or otherwise disable an answer that the community deems an exact duplicate of another. The closed answer could later be edited by the poster at which point it would "come alive" again, in case they believed their answer wasn't a duplicate they could clarify as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed before.  The community will vote up what is perceived to be the best answer.  So the duplicates will filter down in time.